# How to get firestore data in another widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, android-context

**What the app can do so far:** So far, I have an app that shows markers on a Google Map that get the coordinates from Firestore.

**What I want:** I want that when the user presses a marker, he comes to another screen on which some more data is presented (the data is also on the firestore).

**The problem:** I don't know how to get the data (for example the name) on the screen on which the details are to be displayed.

I have a onTap function, which calls `goToDetailPage()`

That`s the goToDetailPage() function:

```
void goToDetailPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new detailPage()));
  }
```

That's the code for "drawing" the marker:

```
 void initMarker(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position:
            LatLng(specify['location'].latitude, specify['location'].longitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: specify['name'], snippet: 'Shop'),
        onTap: () {
          goToDetailPage();
        });
    print(specify['location'].latitude);
    nameTest = specify['name'];
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
      print(markerId.toString() + '__________________________');
    });
  }
```

That's the code from the detail Page:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Detail Page'),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[Text(specify['name'])]),
    );
```

The problem is that the specify from the specify['name'] in the detail page is red underlined and I don`t know what's the reason for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second page:

```
class Tester extends StatefulWidget {

  String dataFromLastPage;
  Tester({Key key, this.dataFromLastPage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TesterState createState() => _TesterState();
}

class _TesterState extends State<Tester> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.dataFromLastPage); //"thisWillGoToTheNextPage!"
  }
}
```

When navigating to that page, send data like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new Tester(dataFromLastPage: 'thisWillGoToTheNextPage!')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and go accoording to what the docs say : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes

However , there are several things the doc doesn't specify like

- To use firestore first , you need to initialize you firestore app , for that you just write a specific piece of code in the main method of your dart file

> ```
> void main() async{
>   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
>   await Firebase.initializeApp();
>   runApp(MyApp());
> }
> ```

- To connect to your firestore database , simply type in your widget build function

  `CollectionReference <Variable name> = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(<Name of collection as string>);`
- Now if you are creating a list , you can simply use a `StreamBuilder` function and get the data in your document via (initialize snapshot as given in the documentation)

> ```
> snapshot.data.docs[index].data()[<Identifier of your document such as
>  'Name' or 'location'>]
> ```